# Is it possible to batch restore backups and remove users from databases in MSSQL 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008, user-management

We're having to do an emergency migration of all of our MSSQL databases from a dying box to a new shiny instance of SQL2008. Unfortunately, we're having to do it by restoring from nightly backups (.bak files).

Is there a way of:

- Automating the restore of a batch of files so as to go:

  - DatabaseName.bak >[restore to]> DatabaseName
- Automating the removal of a specific user from the DB's security>users list?

Yell if you need more information

Comment: Is it the same user or users across all databases?

Comment: Kev, yes, it is. The permissions are the same across most DBs too

Comment: consider posting database-related questions to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ah, I was unaware of dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably would see a couple of T-SQL statements like

```sql
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
   FROM DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorks2012.bak'
   WITH FILE = 6
      NORECOVERY;
```

and

```sql
USE AdventureWorks2012;
DROP USER AbolrousHazem;
GO
```

scripted through something like [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) fit your need.